# Error de parámetros en función python (spyder) modificada

Tags: python, spyder

En spyder python tengo un fichero con diferentes funciones, que luego son llamadas desde otro fichero. En este fichero de funciones, hay una que he modificado pero mantenido el nombre. Los parámetros son diferentes totalmente.
La función inicial tenía este formato:

```
def Gaps(df, comision, porcentual):
```

y la nueva:

```
def Gaps(code, trend=0):
```

Lo he guardado, he reiniciado el kernel y borrado variables, pero continúa saliendo este mensaje de error:

> Cell In[5], line 1
> tec2.Gaps(code, 0)
>
> TypeError: Gaps() missing 1 required positional argument: 'porcentual'

Alguno sabríais a qué es debido y qué puedo hacer para solucionarlo?
Un saludo

Comment: Asegúrate de no tener otra copia del archivo y estar referenciando esa en lugar de la que estás editando. Por otro lado, qué tiene esto que ver con el IDE? Pregunto porque creo que no debe ir la etiqueta [tag:spyder].

Comment: Lo que ocurría es que estaba importando otra librería difrenete donde existía otra versión de esa función. Gracias!